# Move MKMapView point to pixel coordinates

Tags: iphone, ios, dictionary, mapkit, mkmapview

I have a quick question. I am using a custom view as a callout accessory for my map view. I am having some issues with getting the annotation to move to the right bottom corner of the said view. I am currently trying to get the CGPoint coords of the selected annotation, but beyond that I've drawn a blank Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The current code I'm using (I know it is incorrect is:)

```
   CGPoint bottomLeftPoint = CGPointMake(xOffset,[self.internalAnnotationCallout view].frame.size.height);
CLLocationCoordinate2D bottomLeftCoord = [self.branchLocation convertPoint:bottomLeftPoint toCoordinateFromView:self.branchLocation];
MKCoordinateSpan span = {latitudeDelta: kMapMultiLatDelta, longitudeDelta: kMapMultiLatDelta};
  MKCoordinateRegion region = {bottomLeftCoord, span};
 [self.branchLocation setRegion:region animated:YES];
//[self.branchLocation setCenterCoordinate:newCenterCoordinate animated:YES];
```

Comment: EDIT: The callout view has static coordinates. I just want the selected annotation no matter where on the map to go to the bottom right corner of the view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT:

Ok so I messed around with this a little and was able to to put something together that seems to work, hoping that I now actually understand what you're trying to achieve!

```
- (void)shiftToCorner{
    //ignore "Annotation", this is just my own custom MKAnnotation subclass
    Annotation *currentAnnotation = [[mapView selectedAnnotations] objectAtIndex:0];
    [mapView setCenterCoordinate:currentAnnotation.coordinate];

    CGPoint fakecenter = CGPointMake(20, 20);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [mapView convertPoint:fakecenter toCoordinateFromView:mapView];
    [mapView setCenterCoordinate:coordinate animated:YES];
}
```

Let me quickly explain what this does; Let's say you want your annotation to move to a position 20 points in from the right edge and 20 points up from the bottom edge of the map view. If you think about it, if the current annotation is at the center of the map view, then the distance to this point is the same as the distance to (20, 20). This means that we can send our annotation to this point by first centering our map view on the annotation, then animating to (20, 20).

Comment: ack that's pretty tough to read in a comment, can you add it to your question?

Comment: How would I translate the the old coordinate of the selected annotation to the new preset ones?

Comment: Are you trying to move the annotation to a new map coordinate?

Comment: Yes I am trying to move the map so that the selected annotation matches the bottom corner of my view, i.e. assume the bottom corner is CGPoint(160,300). My issue is getting the map to scroll the selected annotation to that point.

Comment: There are two ways to move an annotation: either implement dragging support in your map view delegate (the user still has to actually drag it to a new location) or you can programmatically remove the annotation, change its coordinate, and add it back to the map view.

Comment: Thanks, but I really don't want to remove the annotation. I just want to scroll the mapview so that selected annotation is positioned at the corner of my overlaid "callout" view. I am getting the CGPoint of the annotation but from there on I'm having issues of actually calculating the offset and setting that as a coordinate.

Comment: Ok so you you're not trying to move the annotation relative to the map view, you're trying to scroll the map view into position such that the annotation is in the corner, correct?