# moving MapView programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I have a mapView in which I show a location (represented by custom pin) as seen in screenshot
[image]

How can I move the mapView so that the icon is visible completely?

Comment: this actually helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064044/move-mkmapview-point-to-pixel-coordinates

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this you first need to calculate the point on screen view where you want to scroll (In your case let assume its 20 pixel up to the annotation marker), Then you need to covert this point to Map location so that you can move map center to that location ;-). Following is the code written in **Swift** in **MKMapView delegate** methods where annotation gets tapped.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    let pinLocation = view.annotation.coordinate

    let currentCoordinates = mapView.centerCoordinate // Temporary saved map current center position

    // Temp set map center position to pin location
    mapView.centerCoordinate = pinLocation

    let viewCenter = self.view.center
    let fakecenter = CGPoint(x: viewCenter.x, y: viewCenter.y - 20) // point just up to the center point

    // convert calculetd point to map location co-ordinates
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = mapView.convert(fakecenter, toCoordinateFrom: self.view)

    // reset to previous potion so thet animation start from that
    mapView.centerCoordinate = currentCoordinates
    self.mapView.setCenter(coordinate, animated: true) // change the new center
}
```